# Determine whether this relation is reflexive, symmetric...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Determine whether this relation $R$ on the set of all integers is reflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric and/or transitive where $x\,R\,y$ iff 
$x = y + 1$  **or** $x = y-1$

- It is not reflexive: 
  Let $x = 2$: $2\neq 2 + 1$  **and** $2 \neq 2 - 1$.
- It is symmetric:
  If $x = y + 1$ then $y = x - 1$
  and if $x = y - 1$ then $y = x + 1$.
- It is not anti-symmetric:
  Let $x = 3$ and $y = 2$;
  then $3 = 2 + 1$ ($x\,R\,y$) and $2 = 3 - 1$ ($y\,R\,x$) 
  And let $x = 2$ and $y = 3$;
  then $2 = 3 - 1$ ($x\,R\,y$) and $3 = 2 + 1$ ($y\,R\,x$)
  but $3\neq 2$.

Can anyone prove whether this relation is transitive or not?
thanks.

Comment: Try it for the numbers $1,2,3$.

Comment: $xRy$ iff $x,y$ differ by one. So, if $xRy$ and $yRz$, what can you say about the relationship between $x$ and $z$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did fine with reflexivity, and with symmetry and antisymmetry.

Now, let's look at transitivity:

We can summarize the relation as follows: $xRy$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ differ by $1$.

So, suppose $xRy$ ($x$ and $y$ differ by one) and $yRz$ ($y$ and $z$ differ by one),

What may be the case about the difference between $x$ and $z$?

- (Suspect a counterexample exists: just find $x, y, z$ such that $x = y - 1, y = z - 1 \implies x = z - 2$.
  Or, vice versa, $x = y+1, y = z+1 \implies x = z+2)$

Let $x = 0$, $y = 1$, and $z = 2$, so we certainly have $x, y, z \in \mathbb Z$

- Clearly, $x = y - 1$ since $0 = 1-1$, so $x R y$,
- And $y = z - 1$, since $1 = 2 - 1$, so $y R z$.
- But it is not true that $x = z + 1 $, since $0 \neq  2+1 = 3$  nor
  does $x = z - 1$, since $0 \neq 2 - 1 = 1$.

Hence, $x$ is ***not related*** to $z$, and transitivity fails.

All we need is one counterexample to prove that a relation is non-transitive, and we've just found one such couterexample

Comment: Thanks @amWhy for your answer :)

Comment: done....... :) .

Comment: You're welcome, ammarx!

Answer (score 1):

To disprove, you only need to find a counter example.

Clearly $R 0 1$ and $R 1 0$ hold, but then it would also have to be the case that $R 0 0$ holds, which is not true.

In general, transitive and symmetric would imply reflexive (on its domain) [which would be a contradiction to $R$ not reflexive for 2, which *is* in the domain]: $Rxy$ implies $Rxy$ by symmetry, from which $Rxy \wedge Ryx \implies Rxx$ by transitivity.

Comment: Perhaps you mean *transitive and symmetric*. However a relation can be transitive and symmetric whilst not being reflexive: the empty relation is of course transitive and symmetric, but fails to be reflexive on any non empty set.

Comment: @egreg A transitive and symmetric relation is reflexive on its domain.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro That's of course true. But it's a very common mistake to derive reflexivity from transitivity and symmetry without checking the domain.

Comment: @egreg The proof starts from the assumption $xRy$ for some $y$, so that implies the domain limitation. (Stated another way, if $R$ is transitive and symmetric, then $xRy$ implies $xRx$.)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Is the relation $R=\{(1,1)\}$ reflexive on the set $X=\{0,1\}$? Of course not. This is the kind of error I'm referring to.

Comment: @egreg I usually think of relations as "coming with a domain" $\operatorname{dom} R=\{x\mid \exists y\,xRy\}$, so for me that is a non-example. Of course a (trans. & symm.) relation only makes sense on its given domain, in which case reflexivity is almost tautological: A relation is reflexive except where it isn't (which is to say, outside its domain).

Comment: @egreg, thanks for the remark, fixed.